# Lets say x,y,z are properties of class I need to achieve total = x+y+z and the total should be different for every object i create

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I have a Player class with three Int properties and totalAbilityScore property with computes total of these three Int properties.

```
private var strength : Int?
private var speed : Int?
private var agility : Int?
private var totalAbilityScore : Int?
```

My challenges is to create 15 player objects and no two players can have the same total attribute score (speed + strength + agility = total attribute score) which is less than 100.

I tried to generate 15 unique random numbers and stored in an array using below code. Now my question is what are the possible ways to generate other two distinct variables from each variable in array so that those sum should be less than 100 and distinct from other numbers in array.

```
func randomNumber(between lower: Int, and upper: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower))) + lower
}

func generateRandomUniqueNumbers(forLowerBound lower: Int, andUpperBound upper:Int, andNumNumbers iterations: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard iterations <= (upper - lower) else { return [] }
    var numbers: Set<Int> = Set<Int>()
    (0..<iterations).forEach { _ in
        let beforeCount = numbers.count
        repeat {
            numbers.insert(randomNumber(between: lower, and: upper))
        } while numbers.count == beforeCount
    }
    return numbers.map{ $0 }
}
```

Comment: One way can be to produce 15 unique random numbers under 100 , and then divide it into three parts

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are many ways to achieve this.

Given below is an example:

1. Generate 15 unique random numbers from 5 to 100
2. The numbers generated would be the total score for each player
3. Strength = total % 2
4. Speed = total % 5
5. Agility = total - (strength + speed)

Comment: any reason behind generating between 6 to 100??

Comment: In this example speed can take any value from 0 to 4. So the total needs to be 5 or above

Comment: These are just arbitrary numbers and it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

No need to make your Player properties optionals. Use a struct and make your totals a computed property:

```
struct Player {
    let strength : Int
    let speed : Int
    let agility : Int
    var totalAbilityScore: Int {
        return strength + speed + agility
    }
}
```

---

Check the logic comments inside the method:

```
func generatePlayers(n: Int) -> [Player] {
    var possibleTotals = Array(0..<100)
    var players: [Player] = []
    // make totals a set so it wont rpeat
    var totals: Set<Int> = []
    // loop while totals count it is not reached
    while totals.count < n {
        // pick a random index and remove it
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(possibleTotals.count)))
        totals.insert(possibleTotals[index])
        possibleTotals.remove(at: index)
    }
    // loop through your totals
    for total in totals {
        // make sure you have enough elements to pick two index to split your array from 0 to 99
        if total > 2 {
            // make your indexes a set so it wont repeat
            var indexes: Set<Int> = []
            let array = Array(0..<total)
            while indexes.count < 2 {
                let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total)))
                indexes.insert(index)
            }
            // sort your indexes
            let sortedIndices = indexes.sorted()
            // create 3 array slices
            let a1 = array[0..<sortedIndices[0]]
            let a2 = array[sortedIndices[0]..<sortedIndices[1]]
            let a3 = array[sortedIndices[1]..<array.endIndex]
            // initialize your player with the slices count
            print(total, [a1.count, a2.count, a3.count])
            players.append(Player(strength: a1.count, speed: a2.count, agility: a3.count))
            // take care of very small totals like 0,1 or 2
        } else if total == 2 {
            var values = [0, 1, 1]
            values.indices.dropLast().forEach {
                values.swapAt($0, Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(values.count - $0))) + $0)
            }
            print(values)
            players.append(Player(strength: values[0], speed: values[1], agility: values[2]))
        } else if total == 1 {
            var values = [0, 0, 1]
            values.indices.dropLast().forEach {
                values.swapAt($0, Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(values.count - $0))) + $0)
            }
            print(values)
            players.append(Player(strength: values[0], speed: values[1], agility: values[2]))
        } else  {
            print([0,0,0])
            players.append(Player(strength: 0, speed: 0, agility: 0))
        }
    }
    return players
}
```

---

Testing

```
let players = generatePlayers(n: 15)
```

this will print

> 68 [7, 55, 6]
>
> [0, 0, 0]
>
> 37 [4, 16, 17]
>
> 32 [17, 7, 8]
>
> 72 [0, 52, 20]
>
> 22 [13, 7, 2]
>
> 70 [28, 30, 12]
>
> 18 [2, 4, 12]
>
> 9 [4, 2, 3]
>
> 39 [6, 32, 1]
>
> 31 [18, 2, 11]
>
> 92 [53, 12, 27]
>
> 81 [36, 31, 14]
>
> 98 [65, 9, 24]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple implementation, tweak number give different minimum

```
struct Player {
    var strength = 0
    var speed = 0
    var agility = 0
    var totalAbilityScore = 0
}

func randomNumber(between lower: Int, and upper: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower))) + lower
}

var totals = [Int]()
while totals.count < 15 {
    let i = randomNumber(between: 50, and: 100)
    if let _ = totals.index(of: i) {
        
    } else {
        totals.append(i)
    }
}
var players = totals.map { (i) -> Player in
    var p = Player()
    p.totalAbilityScore = i
    p.strength = randomNumber(between: 2, and: i)-1
    p.agility = randomNumber(between: 2, and: i-p.strength)-1
    p.speed = i-p.strength-p.agility
    return p
}
```

Output:

> Player(strength: 32, speed: 35, agility: 12, totalAbilityScore: 79)
>
> Player(strength: 29, speed: 30, agility: 7, totalAbilityScore: 66)
>
> Player(strength: 34, speed: 34, agility: 1, totalAbilityScore: 69)
>
> Player(strength: 3, speed: 2, agility: 52, totalAbilityScore: 57)
>
> Player(strength: 46, speed: 21, agility: 11, totalAbilityScore: 78)
>
> Player(strength: 36, speed: 16, agility: 19, totalAbilityScore: 71)
>
> Player(strength: 26, speed: 19, agility: 6, totalAbilityScore: 51)
>
> Player(strength: 21, speed: 28, agility: 27, totalAbilityScore: 76)
>
> Player(strength: 65, speed: 2, agility: 20, totalAbilityScore: 87)
>
> Player(strength: 29, speed: 29, agility: 10, totalAbilityScore: 68)
>
> Player(strength: 29, speed: 44, agility: 12, totalAbilityScore: 85)
>
> Player(strength: 55, speed: 7, agility: 32, totalAbilityScore: 94)
>
> Player(strength: 34, speed: 33, agility: 30, totalAbilityScore: 97)
>
> Player(strength: 41, speed: 51, agility: 7, totalAbilityScore: 99)
>
> Player(strength: 73, speed: 10, agility: 5, totalAbilityScore: 88)

Comment: this won't accept totals in a range from 0..<100. What if the player doesn't have any speed agility or strength?

Comment: OP only restriction was that players should have unique totals from `0..<100`

Comment: actually its kinda nonsense if player have 0 point of something, and i already said, tweak number to make bounds, i specify the range of 50-100 just for example, he can just make the lower bounds to 0 to product 0-100, im sure its not that hard

Comment: If you try your code with lower than 3 it would probably crash. Check OP comment at the other answer "any reason behind generating between 6 to 100??" If having totals below 3 or not is allowed you need to ask OP not me

Comment: btw instead of using index(of:) just use a set or just check if it contains. You are discarding the resulting index anyway

Comment: Indeed, even if the loop will run same amount, count Set might be faster than check index

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random agility score under 100 and then divide the score equally between the traits. This can also be done randomly, by generating three numbers that sum up to 1 and multiplying each one of them by our random agility score.

This will leave us with three random scores that sum up to be less than 100, but to ensure the total score is unique for a player, we will use a simple while loop to loop until we have an array full of players with unique scores.

```
class Player {
    private (set) var agility: Int
    private (set) var speed: Int
    private (set) var strength: Int

    var totalAbilityScore: Int { return agility + speed + strength }

    init() {
        let ability = Double(arc4random_uniform(100))
        let randoms = [drand48(), drand48(), drand48()]
        let factors = randoms.map { $0 * Double(1 / randoms.reduce(0, +)) }

        agility = Int(ability * factors[0])
        speed = Int(ability * factors[1])
        strength = Int(ability * factors[2])
    }

    static func generate(_ n: Int) -> [Player] {
        var players = [Int:Player]()

        while players.count < n {
            let player = Player()
            let score = player.totalAbilityScore

            if !players.keys.contains(score) {
                players[score] = player
            }
        }

        return [Player](players.values)
    }
}
```